# Ember hide parent template when viewing sub-route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am making a simple blog for my website with Ember.

My routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', { path: '/' });
  this.route('blog', function() {
    this.route('post', {path: '/:post_id'});
  });
});
```

I want it so when I click on a post in `/blog` and wind up at `/blog/:post_id` I hide the content of the `blog.hbs` file and only show the `blog/post.hbs` content.

I tried specifying the render template explicitly in my `post.js` route file, but things kept working in the same fashion.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('post', params.post_id, { reload: true });
  },
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('blog/post');
  }
});
```

Reading through the documentation here didn't cue me into any other ideas.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/rendering-a-template/

Am I fundamentally using Ember wrong?  Should my post URL not be a sub-route of Blog if I want to hide a parent templates content?

Comment: If your templates aren't nested then why are you nesting the routes?

Comment: @Kitler they are nested.  I assumed if I explicitly called the template in the route then it may only show that template.

Comment: You could move the blog template/route/controller to blog.index

Comment: @Kitler Yes that is another great option.  I wasn't thinking about the problem properly.  I actually like that solution a bit more because that would maintain a cleaner directory structure.  Thank you for the recommendation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, @remi answer do the job, but it is not the correct according to the convention.

When you create something like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('blog', function() {
    this.route('post', {path: '/:post_id'});
  });
});
```

It implicit creates

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('blog', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/' }); // <------ this one
    this.route('post', {path: '/:post_id'});
  });
});
```

So, if you got nested router, but don't want to nest templates, rename the blog template (and route) to index. It will be something like renaming:

**with POD**

*app/blog/route.js -> app/blog/index/route.js*

*app/blog/template.hbs -> app/blog/index/template.hbs*

**No POD**

*app/routes/blog.js -> app/routes/blog/index.js*

*app/templates/blog.hbs -> app/templates/blog/index.hbs*

This is documented on the [Official guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes) (the link is for the latest version, but it is also applicable for older ones)

Comment: Is there a way to only partially nest the template? Like {{#if outlet}} or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know, why you nest the route if you don't want the content to be nested. Anyways...

If you just want the url to reflect your nesting, try this:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home', { path: '/' });
  this.route('blog', { path: 'blogs' });
  this.route('post', { path: 'blog/:post_id'});
});
```

Comment: I mainly want the nesting for URL reasons.  I wanted it to be site.com/blog/:id instead of site.com/:id.  Is this the only way to do it?  Seems hacky, and like I probably am using things not in an intended fashion.

Comment: Ahhh, now that edit is exactly what I was looking for.  So simple, I can't believe I overlooked that.  Thank you!  You can remove the first part of your response so there is less snark in it and I will mark as answer.

Comment: Okay, I removed the other stuff ;)