# Render only outlet template if outlet exists

Tags: ember.js

I have route 'A' and subroute 'B'. I don't want to render the template of Route  'A' if the subroute 'B' is accessed. But if am I not at subroute level, I want to render the template of route 'A'.

Is there a way to achieve this? I tried following for template 'A':

```
{{#if outlet}}
    <h1>Subroute</h1>
    {{outlet}}
{{else}}
    <h1>Route</h1>
{{/if}}
```

Pity enough this does not work (outlet is a 'magic' word, it is not a normal variable). I could do it by using css's absolute positioning, but I would like to use a more Ember way if that's possible!

---

Not nesting the routes like Remi says in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34813398/2049986 is no option for me, because the model of Route 'A' is used in subroute 'B' (and other subroutes of route 'A').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, just after more thinking, you can make use of the `index` subroute... Just remove the template of route 'A' and place it contents at the index subroute. This template will only be shown if you do not access a 'normal' subroute.