# How do you create nested dynamic routes with ember.js where child route replaces parent's template?

Tags: ember.js

On Ember 3.15 (Octane)

I'm trying to create the following routes in my application

```
/cars
/cars/:car_id
/cars/:car_id/:model_id
```

The first two are fine and I've been able to create them using `ember-cli`

```
ember g route cars
ember g route cars/car
```

The problem with the third one is that I need the `model` template to be shown under the `cars` template, ie. replace the `car` template. So if I put an `{{outlet}}` on the `car` template, the `model` template is rendered in it fine but obviously with that `{{outlet}}` nothing happens when I navigate to `/cars/5/2`

My router looks like this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('cars', function(){
    this.route('car', { path: ':car_id'}, function() {
      this.route('model', { path: ':model_id' });
    });
  });
});
```

I've tried using an index route `ember g route cars/car/index` but the problem with this that the `params` are not available in the `index` route and can only be accessed on the `car` route.

As plan b I've created the car and model routes as top level routes ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34813398/2025666)), but I'd like to achieve the above because of a few reasons

- it seems more logical ie, structuring the app based on the nesting of the routes
- I have many nested routes and creating all of them as first level routes will become hard to maintain
- ember doesn't apply the `active` class correctly with this configuration. For example if I have a navbar with `Cars` as an link, I'd want it to have the *active* styling on all three pages. But this doesn't work anymore because the second route will be called something like `car` and the third one something like `model`.
- there are some issues with the urls that are created by default using `<LinkTo />`.

So if I have something like this in my `car` template

```
<ul>
  {{#each @model.models as |model|}}
    <li><LinkTo @route="model" @model={{model}}> {{model.title}} </LinkTo></li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The actual link works properly in that it takes me to the correct model page, however, the url is shown as `/cars/undefined/undefined`. (Although this is fixable by passing `@models={{array @model.id model.id}}`, it seems like a workaround at this point)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is indeed to use the `index` route.

So have `cars.car.index` and `cars.car.model`. However you should use the `cars.car` route to load the common `car` model. Then you can access it in the `cars.car.index` route with [`this.modelFor('cars.car')`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.15/classes/Route/methods/modelFor?anchor=modelFor).

Then you can access the `params.car_id` in the `cars.car` route, use it to load the car, and then access this car from the `cars.car.index` and `cars.car.model` routes with `modelFor`.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it. `this.modelFor` was the missing piece. I do have to say that this seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: Indeed, the routing layer of ember is a bit aged. It works pretty good, so ember focused really on the component layer and the general object model with octane. I hope there will be some work on it now that octane is shipped.